# Bluetooth issues in Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04, bluetooth

Before this gets marked as duplicate, I have tried the other "fixes" on this site as well as other fixes suggested on other sites - many of which were solutions for people who described similar issues and benefited from the solution.

What's the issue? Bluetooth works fine until it doesn't.. the Gnome switch has no effect and nothing seems to be able to put Bluetooth back to work other than a reboot/restart of my computer, which is inconvenient for obvious reasons.

Here's a list of things I have tried

- upgrading/reinstalling Bluez
- moving from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04
- upgrading my BIOS
- the "sudo rmmod btusb && sudo modprobe btusb" solution
- reinstalling Ubuntu
- checking "rfkill list" - everything seems to be unblocked
- using "rfkill" to block then unblock bluetooth
- I have tried so many fixes I can't list them all

What I do know from poking around is that something suddenly goes wrong with the "driver/adapter/controller/something like that" and it can no longer be found (that is until I reboot/restart)

Running "hcitool dev" while Bluetooth is dead returns an empty list.

I have been researching and going at this issue for months now - so reconsider before marking as duplicate because other entries on this site either :

- Don't describe the same issue
- I have tried them and they don't solve my issue

Please be encouraged to suggest obvious fixes/solutions.. I will try them and if they don't work I edit this post and add them to my "tried this already" list.

PS - WiFi is sometimes dead also when I boot up my system. However, unlike bluetooth, if it is on once the system starts it stays on. That is, there is a random chance that WiFi may/may not exist upon booting up computer.. so I keep booting up/restarting until I find WiFi working, in which case it stays working until I reboot - after which there's a random chance of finding that it exists upon booting/restarting up again, etc etc.

Comment: Is  WiFi and or the Bluetooth a dongle?

Comment: @David No, I am using a Laptop: Lenovo Ideapad L340 15IRH

Comment: Still could have been dongle I assume from your answer they are built in.

Comment: @David Yup they are built-in